# neo4j nodejs strength or properties's relationship modified : how to do it?

Tags: node.js, neo4j, graph-databases

I meet a problem with count request of neo4j with nodejs.

Here my problem :
When I insert a data, it will present like this:

```
start a = node(0)

create unique a-[:HAS_ID]->(b{id:'xx'})

create unique b-[:HAS_INFO]->(c{info:'xx'})

return a,b,c;
```

because it's unique node, so that it will not insert a new node if there are a same node exist. But, I wanna count how many request to call this query.
Ex :

```
   request: -domain/id01/info

     --return a node[0], b node[1] and c node[2]
```

add another data:

```
     request: -domain/id02/info
      -- return : a node[0], b node[3], c node[4]
```

call it again :

```
     request: -domain/id01/info

     --return a node[0], b node[1] and c node[2] //but here is any attribute or properties count to 2.
```

I've read any solution about strength. It told me create an properties of relationship as example :

```
     [:HAS_INFO{strength:num}]
```

and let it increase but I still don't get it. 
Anyone please give me solution and tell me how to do it.
Thank you.

more info : [Representing (and incrementing) relationship strength in Neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474781/representing-and-incrementing-relationship-strength-in-neo4j)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `CASE` statement, see http://gist.neo4j.org/?6052414 for an example. Feel free to for the underlying gist and improve it!

```
MATCH path=(a)-[rel:HAS_INFO]->(b)
WHERE a.name?='A' AND b.name?='Info'
SET rel.weight = (
  CASE
   WHEN not(has(rel.weight))
   THEN 0
   ELSE rel.weight + 1
  END)
RETURN path, rel.weight;
```